# java string with English and Chinese text

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a runtime string that could contain English text with Chinese or Japanese text. e.g. John (漢字). I wanted to parse this text and extract non English characters.

indexOf brackets returns -1. Could anyone point me to right direction?

```
String str = "John (漢字)";
int startIndex = str.indexOf("(");
int endIndex = str.indexOf(")");
```

Comment: It is a pain to deal with Chinese characters using Java. I am curious what solution will be given here as well.

Comment: Check your bracket characters. There are many "similar looking" characters in the Unicode standard....

Comment: The parentheses are separating it from the latin script

Comment: @bmargulies, its Kanji not Hanzii

Comment: I need to extract Chinese or Japanese text from the string. so I can do substring of the main string. str.substring(startIndex+1, endIndex)

Comment: Probably Full Width parens.

Comment: Try it without the Kanji characters in the string. This will help you tell if it's the parentheses or the Kanji characters that are the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it runs well  when I try  your code~    [image]

but it  return  -1  means  it doesn't have the symbol in the string ,please check again  . you can transform the symbol to int and compared!

Comment: Thanks, I did further testing to get code of the bracket value and its 65288 and not 40. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Very glad to help you .  I searched that the encoding  type could also affect the result!

Comment: @mathew: was the source (`str`) or the sought (`indexOf`) bracket value 65288? It might also be worth updating your question accordingly if possible using the Stack Overflow UI and your browser. :)

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code with a couple of `System.out.println` statements added:

```
public class CJKText {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "John (漢字)";
        int startIndex = str.indexOf("(");
        System.out.println("startIndex: " + startIndex);
        int endIndex = str.indexOf(")");
        System.out.println("endIndex: " + endIndex);
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
startIndex: 5
endIndex: 8
```

Please verify that the code posted is the code you are examining in your debugger - perhaps as a number of commenters have said your actual code contains characters that *look* like Unicode [0x28](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0028/index.htm) and [0x29](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0029/index.htm) parentheses but which are in fact not those character codes.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to extract the Kanji/Hanzi part, should try something like this:

```
System.out.println( str.replaceAll("\\P{IsHan}+",""));
```

### Oops!

This would not help, if your bracets are also in the `Han` script...